# Datasize problem

Tags: files, directory

I have a problem with the Data size.
The files and the directory’s are showed with the size. I don’t want to see the size of the files and directory. How can I deactivate it? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nautilus -> preferences -> Files preferences

This will show: nothing, size and modified date when you make the icons larger (control +) or smaller (control -). Put the all to "none" to not show anything.

[image]

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]